# Flutter IOS Push Notification warning

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, app-store-connect

I have no intension of using push notification in my app.

But when I click trash can in the screenshot below to remove push notification utility, the push notification pops up again.
Image:
[image: trash can in the push notification capability]

Perhaps there is a framework or library I'm using in flutter requires push notification?
I have checked all but I am not sure:

```
PODS:
  - audio_session (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - audioplayers_darwin (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - device_info (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - ffmpeg-kit-ios-min-gpl (5.1)
  - ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl (5.1.0):
    - ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/min-gpl (= 5.1.0)
    - Flutter
  - ffmpeg_kit_flutter_min_gpl/min-gpl (5.1.0):
    - ffmpeg-kit-ios-min-gpl (= 5.1)
    - Flutter
  - Flutter (1.0.0)
  - flutter_native_splash (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - flutter_nearby_connections (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - SwiftyJSON (~> 4.0)
  - FMDB (2.7.5):
    - FMDB/standard (= 2.7.5)
  - FMDB/standard (2.7.5)
  - image_picker_ios (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - just_audio (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - libwebp (1.2.4):
    - libwebp/demux (= 1.2.4)
    - libwebp/mux (= 1.2.4)
    - libwebp/webp (= 1.2.4)
  - libwebp/demux (1.2.4):
    - libwebp/webp
  - libwebp/mux (1.2.4):
    - libwebp/demux
  - libwebp/webp (1.2.4)
  - path_provider_foundation (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - FlutterMacOS
  - sign_in_with_apple (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - sqflite (0.0.3):
    - Flutter
    - FMDB (>= 2.7.5)
  - SwiftyJSON (4.3.0)
  - video_player_avfoundation (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
  - video_thumbnail (0.0.1):
    - Flutter
    - libwebp
```

When I set automatic signing, archive, and then upload it, I receive an email saying :

"""
ITMS-90078: Missing Push Notification Entitlement - Your app appears to register with the Apple Push Notification service, but the app signature's entitlements do not include the 'aps-environment' entitlement.
"""

I don't want to set this capability because I really don't use any notifications. I have nothing to say for the notification during review.

I searched through the packages and I revoked my certificate. I have also added and deleted the notification in my certificate.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have no any intention of using push notification but I can see a problem from your screenshot. Just remove the Push Notification capability as shown in the screenshot below.

[image: Solution]

Comment: It keeps spring out even I delete